Как ограничить владение папкой и все что в ней (на любом уровне) для определенных лиц через CODEOWNERS?
Есть вот такой файлик:
docs/CODEOWNERS
[Quotas]
domains/quotas/ @vasya @petya
    
[Resources]
domains/resources/core/ @vasya @petya
domains/resources/ @vasya @petya @sasha @kirill @olga

Я хочу чтобы папкой "domains/resources/" владели все указанные лица, но вот доступ к папке "domains/resources/core/" был только у "@vasya @petya", а все остальные (касается не только "@sasha @kirill @olga") изменения в ней аппрувить не могли.
Я пробовал менять строчки местами - не помогло. Все равно GitLab говорит, что владеют этой папкой "@vasya @petya @sasha @kirill @olga".
